# Using a value from model and javascript together in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use a variable from model:

> Model.ActionId

and a varialble from javascript (selected index of dropdown)

> $("#ddlMethod").val()

together in a if condition.

I have tried:

```
@if (Model.ActionID== 0 && $("#ddlMethod").val()== 2)
        alert("yes");
```

another:

```
if (@Model.ActionID== 0 && $("#ddlMethod").val()== 2)
        alert("yes");
```

assigning the values first:

```
var selectedMethod = $("#ddlMethod").val();
    var actionId = @Model.ActionID;
    if (actionId == 0 && selectedMethod == 2)
        alert("yes");
```

None of them worked. Help.

[image]

Comment: where you try use it? in separated script or inside page? you you put this scripts to yout page - last two variants should work

Comment: inside page only, bt no, its not working

Comment: it working, try fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sGcIho

Comment: @SurajS, see my update answer on why they didnt initially work

Answer (score 1):

The simply way would be to put the model value in a hidden element like

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.ActionID" id="ActionID"/>
```

and then in your javascript

```
var selectedMethod = $("#ddlMethod").val();
var actionId = $("#ActionID").val();
if (actionId == 0 && selectedMethod == 2)
    alert("yes");
```

**Update**

```
if (@Model.ActionID== 0 && $("#ddlMethod").val()== 2)
        alert("yes");
```

will not work because you need to properly escape razor code when mixing with javascript by putting it in a code block

```
@{ ... } or @if, etc.
```

and putting the code itself in an escaped sequence

```
@: or the <text> tag.
```

Try

```
 @if (<text> '@Model.ActionID' </text> == 0 && $("#ddlMethod").val()== 2){
      <script>
                alert("yes");
      </script>
}
```

Comment: are you try your last suggestion?

Comment: is it becasue of the single quotes in '@Model.ActionID' ?

Comment: nope, in this case parser don't know where used c# code, and where javascript

Comment: @Grundy, no, the last code snipped is in Razor view itself, not between <script></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78690/discussion-between-grundy-and-ammarcse).

Answer (score 1):

if your script in the page so you have a few way for use server variable in your client code:

1. use directly

   ```
   if (@Model.ActionID == 0 && $("#ddlMethod").val()== '2')
       alert("yes");
   ```

   in this case it rendered for `Model.ActionID = 0` like

   ```
   if (0 == 0 && $("#ddlMethod").val()== '2')
       alert("yes");
   ```
2. render this script tag only for needed action id like

   ```
   @if (Model.ActionID == 0){
       <script type="text/javascript">
           if( $("#ddlMethod").val()== '2')
               alert("yes");
       </script>
   }
   ```

   in this case this sctipt rendered and executed only when `Model.ActionID == 0`

If your script in separated file then you again have a few way:

use hidden field as suggest @AmmarCSE, or save `Model.ActionID` to global varibale in your page

```
var modelActionId = @Model.ActionID
```

and use it in script

```
if (modelActionId == 0 && $("#ddlMethod").val()== '2')
    alert("yes");
```

**NOTE:** method [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/), in your case, return *string* rather than number

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but the first one does not work. gives error as "incorrect syntax.". '@Model.ActinId' works.. with single quotes.

Comment: I checked the fiddle, don't know whats the difference.. attched the screen shot.. ;)

Comment: @SurajS, can you provide a code around this? what version mvc you use?